# Why Cant I Click an Element in Selenium?

Tags: python, xpath, selenium, click

I am trying to click an element in Selenium.

The site is: url = "http://jenner.com/people"

The xpath for the element is: url = //div[@class='filter offices']

Here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='filter offices']")
element.click()
```

When I click the element, the drop down for offices should appear.  Instead, when I click the element, nothing happens.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are clicking on div that contains other div with event listener. You should click on div where listener ist registered. This xpath should work:

```
//div[@class='filter offices']/div[@class='header']
```

Comment: How did you know that the listener is registered on the child div and not on the one containing 'filter offices'?

Comment: How can you know where the listener event is registered?

Comment: Open the website in Developer Tools. In my Firefox, for example, there's a bubble **event** near the element. If you click that bubble, you'll get more details. If there is no bubble, search for the right element above or below in the tree till you've found it, it's only important that the element is under the mouse cursor.

Answer (score 7):

Here, I give you working script which select location.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver.exe')
url="https://jenner.com/people"
try:
    driver.get(url)
    element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='filter offices']")
    element.click()
    time.sleep(5)
    element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='search_offices_chicago']")
    element.click()
    time.sleep(5)
except Exception as e:
    print e
    driver.quit()
driver.quit()
```