# selenium python click on element nothing happens

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to click on the Gmail link on the Google frontpage in Selenium with the WebDriver on Python. My code basically replicates the one found here: [Why Cant I Click an Element in Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16511059/why-cant-i-click-an-element-in-selenium)

My Code:

```
import selenium.webdriver as webdriver
firefox = webdriver.Firefox()
firefox.get("http://www.google.ca")
element = firefox.find_element_by_xpath(".//a[@id='gb_23']")
element.click()
```

The webdriver loads the page and then nothing happens. I've tried using the ActionChains and move_to_element(element), click(element), then perform() but nothing happens either.

Comment: xpath is never a good thing to use with selenium. Try searching strictly by id since you have it

Comment: The code works for me..could you test the same code but using chrome instead of firefox?

Comment: You could try downgrading firefox.  I've read that new versions of firefox often break Selenium interactions.

Comment: the thing is that my work uses firefox and im trying to learn selenium for it. I'm trying to use xpath because the Web App that I will be testing doesn't have IDs for the elements that I need to click...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `find_element_by_id` method:

```
element = firefox.find_element_by_id("gb_23")
element.click()
```

or correct your xpath to:

```
"//a[@id='gb_23']"
```

[Here you have nice tutorial.](http://zvon.org/xxl/XPathTutorial/General/examples.html)

Comment: Hmm, strange... Try it: `firefox.click("xpath=//a[@id='gb_23']")`

Answer (score 1):

try this because i can't see this id in the html:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.google.ca")
element = driver.find_element_by_link_text("Gmail")
element.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(button).click(button_sub).perform()
```

You can also use `ClickElement`.